# shell: create Shortcut command (alias or function) for working with IP address as arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, ksh

I am not sure if I performed the following illegal or true

but what I need is - to create set of ready commands
so if I need to use , for example to match IP address with 4 octet
I can use the command -  **command_that_match_four_octet**

Please advice if I performed correctly the following and, I want to know if the following syntax will not cause troubles.

```
[root@su1a /tmp]#  command_that_match_four_octet=" grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' "

[root@su1a /tmp]# command_that_match_three_three_octet=" grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' "
```

.

```
[root@su1a /tmp]# echo 23.4.5.1  | eval $command_that_match_four_octet
   23.4.5.1

[root@su1a /tmp]# echo 23.4.5 | eval $command_that_match_three_three_octet
   23.4.5
```

Comment: Maybe a question for http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Shot answer is Yes, but no. This may work, but using `eval` is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you call `shortcut` seem to be a kind of `alias` or more complex `functions`.

for answering you ask, you could:

```
alias checkCommand="grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'"
echo 23.4.5.1  | checkCommand
23.4.5.1
```

or

```
function checkIsIp() {
    grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'
}
echo 23.4.5.1  | checkIsIp
```

There is a bash function that will check for IP (v4) and more this will compute 32bit integer if argument is a valid IP and return a `RC > 0` if else:

```
function check_Is_Ip() {
    local IFS=.
    set -- $1
    [ $# -eq 4 ] || return 2
    local var
    for var in $* ;do
        [ $var -lt 0 ] || [ $var -gt 255 ] && return 3
      done
    echo $(( ($1<<24) + ($2<<16) + ($3<<8) + $4))
}
```

than now:

```
if check_Is_Ip 1.0.0.1 >/dev/null; then echo It is. ;else echo There is not. ;fi
It is.

if check_Is_Ip 1.255.0.1 >/dev/null; then echo It is. ;else echo There is not. ;fi
It is.

if check_Is_Ip 1.256.0.1 >/dev/null; then echo It is. ;else echo There is not. ;fi
There is not.
```

and useable for IP calculation:

There is the back function:

```
int2ip() {
    echo $(($1>>24)).$(($1>>16&255)).$(($1>>8&255)).$(($1&255))
}

check_Is_Ip 255.255.255.0
4294967040
check_Is_Ip 192.168.1.31
3232235807

int2ip $((4294967040 & 3232235807))
192.168.1.0
```

So as a good practice, you could:

```
function die() {
    echo "Error: $@" >&2
    exit 1
}

netIp="192.168.1.31"
netMask="255.255.255.0"

intIp=$(check_Is_Ip $netIp) || die "Submited IP: '$netIP' is not an IPv4 address."
intMask=$(check_Is_Ip $netMask) || die "Submited Mask: '$netMask' not IPv4."
netBase=$(int2ip $(( intIp & intMask )) )
netBcst=$(int2ip $(( intIp | intMask ^ ( (1<<32) - 1 ) )) )
printf "%-20s: %s\n" \
    Address $netIp Netmask $netMask Network $netBase Broadcast $netBcst

Address             : 192.168.1.31
Netmask             : 255.255.255.0
Network             : 192.168.1.0
Broadcast           : 192.168.1.255
```

Where check, validation and conversion of inputs are done is only one operation:

```
intMask=$(check_Is_Ip $netMask) || die "Submited Mask: '$netMask' not IPv4."
```

If `$netMask` don't match IPv4, the command `check_Is_Ip` will fail, then `die` will be executed. If else, result of conversion will be stored in `intMask` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a shortcut to another command, you can use the builtin shell command `alias`. For more info, you can see `man bash`.

As an example, you can use:

```
$ alias your_command_name='your complicated and long command'
```

Comment: I need only to know if can use the commands as I write in my question , I only want to understand if they are correctly good enough